# If arriving in Estonia in winter from a warm climate, is it easy to find good secondhand winter clothes?

Tags: budget, shopping, clothing, winter, estonia

I just flew from Bangkok where it's 30 degrees C to Tallinn, where it's -1. I have some warm clothes that were enough for early spring in northern Japan, but I think I'll need something better if I'll be in northern Europe climates through the winter.

But having spent most of my money travelling around Asia for ten months, I'm now very budget conscious.

I don't need designer or even fashionable. I need functional and cheap. I always find that if there are used clothing shops you can get much better quality secondhand than you can get new for the same price. But Estonia isn't at the very cheapest end of the range for Europe. Are there shops for used gear? (It's not practical for me to use classified ads, apps, or Internet.)

Comment: I'm not sure how up-to-date it is, but [this map collection](http://goo.gl/wjQpj4) has a fair number of secondhand shop locations.

Answer (score 6):

Yes! Estonia is actually awesome for thrift shopping for clothes!

There are actually lots of used clothes shops here in Tallinn and the prices are low and the quality is high. There is even a chain of stores called [**Humana**](https://www.humanae.ee/?lang=en), including some which are **Humana Vintage**, which I suppose sell more collectible or designer stuff.

At the moment Humana is selling everything at half the marked price. I bought a fantastic winter coat that doesn't seem old for €10. And there are many shops besides Humana.

There is another chain that I've only visited one branch of. It's called [**KiloMax**](http://kilomax.ee/en/) and they have a nifty gimmick where the price is by weight. They charge a different price per kilo depending on what day of the month it is. The 31st is the cheapest. They weigh each item separately.

(Unlike in Japan, these "trendy" secondhand shops in Estonia seem to only sell clothes.)